# How to create video campaign without adwords?

Tags: google-ads-api

adwords api is not supported with video campaigns.Through templateAd we can create video ad.but it is also not supporting with video campaigns in adwords api. getting error while creating video ad.

```
    No handlers could be found for logger "googleads.soap"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_videoAdd.py", line 105, in <module>
    main(adwords_client, 62216880120)
  File "test_videoAdd.py", line 86, in main
    ads = ad_group_ad_service.mutate(operations)
  File "/home/sys1010/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 1391, in MakeSoapRequest
    e.detail, errors=error_list, message=e.message)
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsServerFault: [OperationAccessDenied.MUTATE_ACTION_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_CLIENT @ operations[0]]
```

My code is

```
import urllib2
from googleads import adwords


AD_GROUP_ID = '62216880120'


def main(client, ad_group_id):
      # Initialize appropriate service.
      ad_group_ad_service = client.GetService('AdGroupAdService', version='v201806')


      video = {
          'xsi_type': 'Video',
          'youTubeVideoIdString': "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRTlNFPQCHk",
          'type': 'VIDEO'
      }

      ad_data = {
          'uniqueName': 'adData',
          'fields': [
              {
                  'name': 'video',
                  'fieldMedia': video,
                  'type': 'VIDEO'
              }
          ]
      }

      video_ad = {
          'xsi_type': 'TemplateAd',
          'name': 'Ad for video',
          'templateId': 49,
          'finalUrls': ['https://www.google.com'],
          'displayUrl': 'www.google.com?tip=ENTER_YOUR_OWN_FINAL_AND_DISPLAY_URLS',
          'dimensions': {
              'width': '300',
              'height': '250'
          },
          'templateElements': [ad_data]
      }

      ad_group_ad = {
          'adGroupId': ad_group_id,
          'ad': video_ad,
          'status': 'PAUSED'
      }

      operations = [
          {
              'operator': 'ADD',
              'operand': ad_group_ad
          }
      ]
      ads = ad_group_ad_service.mutate(operations)
```

can somebody help me out of this error.Is there any libraries to create video campaigns programatically.